# synchronized ArrayList vs synchronized method block

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, synchronization, thread-safety

I have 2 code snippets which will do the same thing which makes thread safe. first one does it using Collections.synchronizedList, Example:

```
DataServiceRequest request = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<DataServiceRequest>());
```

Second one do the same thing by synchronizing the method, Example:

```
public synchronized void addRequest(DataServiceRequest request) {
   this.getRequests().add(request);
}
```

What would be the most efficient and safest way When comparing with performance from above 2 examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is really just syntactic sugar for the second (it returns a wrapper list that puts `synchronized (mutex)` around each call), so it is unlikely to make any difference from a performance point of view.

As for "which is the safest way" - that depends on your coding standards. You must pay attention to the documents for [`Collections.synchronizedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)) if you use it, particularly:

> it is critical that all access to the backing list is accomplished through the returned list.

and

> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize **on the returned list** when iterating over it

You'll still have the same issue when iterating a list that you control the synchronization of - this is just saying that the mutex in use for `synchronizedList` is the list itself. If you control the synchronization you just need to consistently use the same mutex for all thread-safe access to the backing list.

Answer (score 1):

Your question might imply that you don't plan to synchronize on *all* list operations, not just those that change the list. If so, then this would be wrong thinking. But even if not so, using `synchronizedList` wrapper takes that worry away from your program because it guarantees that all method calls are synchronized.

The one thing that `synchronizedList` cannot guarantee is synchronization over the block of code which consumes a list iterator. This is still something you'll need to do inside your own synchronized block.